# I want to store the filter expression after the ok button on devexpress

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to store the filter expression after the ok button is pres on DevExpress filter and I don't know how to do that.

I want the expression so I can put her in the database.
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ok Button click event you can take the filter string as

```
string criteria = yourGridVIew.ActiveFilterString ;
```

You can later reassign to the grid as

```
yourGridView.ActiveFilterString = "([ProductID] = 1 OR [ProductID] = 3 " + 
  "OR [ProductID] > 10) AND [Discount] = 0"; // example
```

For AspXGridVIew:

```
string filter =YourGridView.FilterExpression;
```

Comment: My code doesn't recognize the ActiveFilterString. I'm using AspGridView. and where I have to put this line of code?

Comment: use filterExpression property.